# CSS id not working in the div

Tags: html, css

I have been trying to learn horizontal lists in html. I have the following code,

### CSS:

```
#list li
{
    text-decoration:none; 
    display: inline;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding-right: 20px;    
}
</style>
```

### HTML:

```
<div >
<ul id="list">
    <li>Store </li> 
    <li>Mac </li>
    <li>IPod </li>
    <li>IPhone </li>
    <li>IPad </li>
    <li>ITunes </li>
    <li>Support </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

When I put the id in the div tag (`<div id="list">`)then it does not show the list horizontally while the current code displays the list horizontally. I don't get the reason behind it. Please help me clear the concept. Thanks

Comment: `list` is not a class, it is an id. CSS classes are declared with a dot `.list`.

Comment: And both ways work in jsFiddle (`<div id="list">` and  `<ul id="list">
`). Which browser are you testing in?

Comment: @Ako: I am using DreamWeaver CS5

Comment: DreamWeaver CS5 is not a browser, it is an editor. Which browser do you test in? Firefox, Safari, Opera, IE, Chrome?

Comment: @Ako: I did not saw that in a browser. I just saw it in the Design tab of DW.

Comment: You should try it in a browser. Your users use a browser to browse your site, not DW.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works just fine if you put the ID on the div element as well.

Have a look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sKaYm/

Your CSS selector `#list li` says "apply this to any list element that is child of an element with ID 'list' - no matter if it is an immediate child or not." - So basically it doesn't matter how many levels of div's or other elements you wrap around your list, it will still select it.

Answer (score 2):

Because a div is not a list element. It has no list-style-type, so it won't change the bullets on any lists within the div. And an 'inline' display type does not propagate down the DOM tree from a parent node, so the inline applies only to the div itself and won't affect the list or li elements.

Comment: Can you please brief me why does inline not propagate down? I would be very thankful. Thanks

Comment: The selector is `#list li` not just `#list`, so that shouldn't be a problem right? The CSS will be applied to any li that is child of the div with id list.

Comment: @Christorer: OP is asking why the styling doesn't apply if the CSS selector points at the div.

Comment: @Akito: think of it as a padding rule. If padding rules propagated down and applied to all child styles, then `padding: 10px` on an element with 10 sub-levels of other elements would end up with the lowest child padded 100px away. Inline is similar. You usually only want to 'float' one element that way, and leave its child elements in standard configurations.

Comment: @MarcB I might be wrong, but as I interpret the question, he is just moving the id attribute from the ul element to the div element, without modifying the selector, and in that case the selector would still work as expected. However, if he indeed modify the selector to actually point to the div, then your absolutely right with your answer.

Comment: @ChristoferEliasson: I meant to ask exactly what you just said in the comment. Sorry if I had not elaborated it clearly.

Comment: @Akito Well in that case, my answer should apply. It should work just fine. If you have a look at the fiddle in my answer, do you still not see the list items in a horizontal line?

Answer (score 1):

According to this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KtF8U/) it works.

Answer (score 1):

list-style-type only changes the marker in front of the item.
to create cross browser horizontal list add float left to each list item :

```
#list li
{
    text-decoration:none; 
    display: inline;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding-right: 20px;   
    float:left;
}
```